# Textarea editor Redactor. Insert value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, redactor

Have field textarea `id="tr"`
using HTML editor Redactor last version
trying to set value of the field exactly haw it is described in API Doc :

```
$('#tr').redactor('insertText', 'text');
```

or

```
$('#tr').redactor('insertHtml', 'text');
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using an old version of redactor, you can try the set API, which I think is a lower-level version of `insertText`/`insertHtml`.

So in your example, it should be:

```
$('#tr').redactor('set', 'Your text goes here');
```

**Update (2015-04-21)**: In redactor v2, the name of the set method was changed:

```
$('#tr').redactor('code.set', 'Your text goes here');
```

**Another Update (2020-04-20)**: In their latest version, Imperavi [changed their syntax](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api-services/source/#s-setcode) and provided two ways to achieve this solution:

```
const editor = $R('#tr');
editor.source.setCode('Your text goes here');
```

or

```
$R('#tr', 'source.setCode', 'Your text goes here');
```

Comment: Thank youuu!! I could not find how to do it in the site's documentation.. I don't really like how it's done, feels a bit strange

Comment: The 2015 update is the ONLY thing tnaat worked for me. It saved my day. The world is a little better because of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code work perfectly for destroy and then update to new.

```
$('#redactor_subcontentid').destroyEditor();
// set it to new 
$('#redactor_subcontentid').redactor().setCode("Your Text");
```

Comment: I couldn't get this one to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 8 from 2013, which has the following code:

```
$( '.redactor' ).setCode( 'text' );
```

I found this in from archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20121228195235/http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api

If none of the above work for you, check which version you have and find the relevant documentation by changing the date on archive.org.