# Redactor: set value of textarea and disable callbacks

Tags: jquery, redactor

I'm using Redactor as a WYSIWYG and setting the html of the textarea with jQuery.

```
$('#description_full').redactor('code.set', 'text goes here', { start: true });
```

(Source: [Textarea editor Redactor. Insert value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590297/textarea-editor-redactor-insert-value-with-jquery))

However, when the code is set using this (which works correctly) the focus also shifts to Redactor, which I'd like to disable. In the API documentation (https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/code/) it appears that I can prevent the change callback with:

```
{ start: true }
```

Unfortunately, this is not preventing the callback which is focusing on the Redactor editor. Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I've found that this is a limitation of Redactor. In order to prevent the callback we need to destroy the object and reinstantiate it with the updated text already inserted into the  input field.